# Windows 10 timer does not automatically sync

Tags: windows-10, sync, timer

**Solved - see below**

My computer time is approx. 5 minutes behind. I can correct it manually, but automatic synchronization never works regardless of the NTP server I use (any of time.nist.gov or the Microsoft default time.windows.com).
When trying to sync, I always receive either 'error...no time data available' or timeout.

* The Windows Time service is running (can be started and stopped)

* The NIST internet time can be manually read from the NIST site.

* The computer was restarted several times.

* The Windows firewall was reset to its default.

**Solved:** The problem was solved, but as I saw many similar problems, I leave this thread to help others.

 I found out that the NIST and Microsoft default Windows NTP servers are too far from my location (Israel), and are probably overloaded or the internet is too slow, causing timeout.

By using a local NTP (in my case: il.pool.ntp.org) the synchronization was instant. 
I would therefore suggest using a local NTP rather than the Windows default.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: If you have solved your problem you should submit an answer instead of modifying your question to contain the solution.  If you do submit an answer, be sure to remove the solution from your question, or I suppose you could wait for somebody to do it for you.  It is very unlikely your problem was caused by the distance you are to the NTP servers.  What is more likely, you have a firewall that is blocking the connection to those address, the fact you have a local NPT server within your networ indicates that might be the case.